# List Indentation same x-cord as header

Tags: html, css

I want to create a `list` that looks kind of like that:
  This is a Header
- This is a list element
- This is an another list element
- This is an another list element
   but with a second line

I tried:

```css
div#first ul{
  padding:0;
}
```

```html
<div id="first">
<h1>This is a Header</h1>
<ul>
  <li>This is a list element</li>
  <li>This is another list element</li>
  <li>This is another list element<br/>but with a break</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

```css
div#second ul{
  padding:0;
}
div#second li{
  list-style-position: inside;
}
```

```html
<div id="second">
<h1>This is a Header</h1>
<ul>
  <li>This is a list element</li>
  <li>This is another list element</li>
  <li>This is another list element<br/>but with a break</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Do you know a simple solution for that?
Preferred without setting any `padding` value to a specific number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this, using a pseudo, would be one option

```css
div#first ul {
  padding:0;
  list-style-type: none;
}
div#first ul li {
  margin: 0 10px;
  position: relative;
}
div#first ul li::before {
  content: '-';
  position: absolute;
  left: -10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="first">
<h1>This is a Header</h1>
<ul>
  <li>This is a list element</li>
  <li>This is another list element</li>
  <li>This is another list element<br/>but with a break</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I am trying for 20 minutes with br and li but I didn't. I think your solution, fair enough.

Comment: Thanks for the idea

Comment: I hoped it would be possible without setting values like the 10px.
But I will stick with your solution 
thanks a lot :)